# PHP Stopping Sleep

Tags: php, sleep

I have a script uses `sleep(1);` like about 20 times but i need to know how is it possible to stop the sleep().

Here is my example:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
echo "hi";
sleep(1);
if ($whatever == "stop")break;
}
?>
```

Whatever is what the user checks, this is for a bot script for a chat so $whatever would be the users message and if it was "stop" the sleep() would stop.

Comment: under what condition would you want the function to not sleep?

Comment: What do you mean by stopping the sleep?

Comment: i want it to stop sleeping, but once it starts i never found a way to make it stop.

Comment: This is the server-side, you aren't expected to receive anything new before completing the code execution.

Comment: PHP, unfortunately, is a very heavy sleeper.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    echo "hi";
    if ($whatever != "stop") {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```